# MongoDB with paged result set sorted by distance

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a large collection of events and am wondering if there is any way to sort them by distance in a paged fashion.

I am using the geoWithin operater to find events within a certain radius but need to order the results by distance and return them in a paged fashion.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to sort by distance based on radius from a center point, I would suggest using a `$near` query with a set [`$maxDistance`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/maxDistance/), instead of `$geoWithin`. The results of this query will be automatically sorted by distance from the center.

As for pagination, you can use the [skip](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/)/[limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) functionality, or incrementally increase the maxDistance.

Comment: I had originally looked at using the $near query operator but it only returned the 100 closest items which wouldn't work in a paging scenario.  It appears that with a 2dsphere index this limitation has been removed.  I have 2 other fields that I am sorting on now but I may be able to use this now.